# How to pass variable number of args to a variadic function

Tags: objective-c, c, variadic-functions

I have a variadic function with the signature:

```
- (id)initWithNumVertices:(NSUInteger)inCount, ...;
```

But I cannot figure out how to construct the ellipsis part from a **variable** number of vertices. How can this be done?

EDIT: sorry I wasn't asking for a way to write this function, I'm asking for a way to call it, using an **unknown** number of variables. The function takes structs and not objects.

If the number of arguments is known, I can do this:

```
[[MyObject alloc] initWithNumVertices:4, v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]];
```

But how can I call this when the number of vertices is unknown?

Comment: To clarify, how are these vertices represented? Are they objects, primitive types, etc? That ties into my answer.

Comment: The vertices are a struct made of 2 floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to call a variadic function if the number of arguments is not known at compile time. If you want to avoid the overhead of using an `NSArray`, the standard way of passing multiple C structs to a method would be using standard C arrays.

```
- (id)initWithVertices:(Vertex *)vertices count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

`NSIndexPath`'s `-indexPathWithIndexes:length:` is an example where this pattern is also used, there are various others, it's fairly common in Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Just use a native C array. A variadic method won't help you here.

---

In your case, since you have an unspecified number of arguments, you'd have to rewrite it in this form:

```
- (id)initWithVertices:(vertex)firstVertex;
```

which runs a while loop until it hits a vertex specified as illegal (that will be your break point), sort of like this:

```
vertex currentVertex, invalidVertex = // some invalid value, like {-1, -1}
while ((currentVertex = va_arg(args, vertex) != invalidVertex) {
    // initialization code with the current vertex
    // when we hit 'invalidVertex', which will be at the end of the list, stop
}
```

Code like that has to be run like this:

```
[[MyObject alloc] initWithVertices:firstVertex, secondVertex, thirdVertex, nullVertex];
```

`nullVertex` has to be at the end of the list in order to specify the last of the valid vertices (much like `NSArray`'s `arrayWithObjects:` method has to have `nil` at the end of the list).

Comment: Thanks but I already have the function working. I just don't know how to call it for the general case of X (unknown) number of vertices. It would be like passing an array except I don't wan't to pass an NSArray due to performance reasons.

Comment: Does my updated answer still not work for you? And why are you worried about performance reasons? Can you specify a little more?

Comment: How can I call initWithVertices: for the general case of X vertices?

Comment: You don't. If it's really that unspecified, pass in an array. Why are you avoiding them?

Comment: The vertices are the same as CGPoint, but I don't want to encode and decode them as NSValues every time I create the object, because I create and destroy these thousands of times per second. If a collection object like NSArray is unavoidable, I will use it, but I wanted to see if there was a faster alternative. Variadic args seems to have been the answer except I don't know how to call it.

Comment: You don't have to. Pass them in in native C arrays. Much faster.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's happened to me before... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to separate the arguments?

```
[[YourObject alloc] initWithNumVertices:7, 8, 9, 10];
```

EDIT | Oh, I think I see what you're asking.  You want to invoke this method dynamically, such as with `objc_msgSend()` or via `NSInvocation`?  Disregard my answer if that's the case.

Comment: Yes except that I can't do this because I don't know how many vertices there are.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, look at libffi (`man ffi'):

> DESCRIPTION
>        The foreign function interface provides a mechanism by which a
>   function can generate a call to
>   another function at runtime without
>   requiring knowledge of
>        the called function's interface at compile time.

You should be able to invoke `objc_msgSend()` using this if I understand correctly.